# Combine column values with separator between them

Tags: excel

I have a column of values and would like to get in one field a comma-concatenated string of those column. I did it indirectly with the following technique:

- Suppose my list is A1:A50
- In column C, for C1, I used `=A1&","`
- For C2 I used `=C1&A2&","`
- Then I auto-filled down
- And so in C60 I had the whole comma-concatenated list of values.

Now, while this did the job, it's very primitive, making no use of any specialized formulas (if one exists for such a job).

I forgot to mention that I have already tried =TRANSPOSE(A1:A100) which is suggested everywhere on the internet, but the formula returns an error (probably due to my data having double-quotes)...

```
[map_lookup("getFireplace", {fireplace[1]})]
[map_lookup("getWc", {wc[1]})]
[map_lookup("getElevator", {elevator[1]})]
[map_lookup("getDevices", {devices[1]})]
[map_lookup("getStorage", {storage[1]})]
[map_lookup("getAc", {ac[1]})]
[map_lookup("getFurnitured", {furnitured[1]})]
```

This is a small extract of the column data I want to get as a comma-concatenated string.

So is there any more advanced/short way to achieve that? TIA

Comment: Did you try TEXTJOIN on the duplicate link? `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:A50)`

Comment: I don't have Office365, I have Office 2019

Comment: Then you either need to do what you are doing or use VBA, there is no other way.  The link has a vba udf that mimic TEXTJOIN.

Comment: What is the problem with TRANSPOSE returning an error? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you try the data I posted above and then do a =TRANSPOSE(A1:A7) ?

Comment: And my guess is that you hitting the limit of Transpose.  It is ridiculously low.  And 50 cells with that much data would come close to it.  With the 7 you show I have no problem with transpose.

Comment: And, just so you know there is a limit to the number of characters that a cell can hold.  There are other ways if all you want is the output that use text editors.  Save the file as a CSV open it in a text editor and replace the line breaks with a comma.  The second most popular answer [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/240858/convert-a-column-into-a-comma-separated-list/1171513#1171513) steps through it using word

Comment: I'm not hitting the char limit. I'm sure about that for two reasons: a. My indirect way has absolutely no problem holding the data of 46 (that's the exact, current number of items in the column) items similar to the 7 ones I pasted here. b. I did a `=TRANSPOSE(A1:A3)` to the exact same data I pasted here, and it couldn't complete that one either...

Comment: BTW, Office 2019 has TEXTJOIN. At least it is listed in the version list: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c

Comment: OMG, TEXTJOIN did the job!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You're a gem my friend! Thank you so very much! :D